# Using JMeter to test server on another continent - bad idea?

Tags: jmeter

Newby question:
If I use JMeter from the UK to do load testing to a webserver on the other side of the planet - Australia - will I get meaningful results, or is the latency going to mess it up?

How else could I test from the UK? 
Is the only solution a commercial product where I can define the region?

Comment: What is your testing goal? If it's to measure performance or capacity of your UK customers to your AUS server, then you are on the right track.

Comment: You can always use a cloud based service like AWS and set up a Jmeter server on the same region/continent.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - you all need an upvote. Site is only for use in Aus, no international customers. The latency over there from east to west is appreciable as it is, but yep I think I can get a plan from all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Elapsed time**. JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter process any client code, for example Javascript.
>
> **Latency**. JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is experienced by a browser or other application client.
>
> **Connect Time**. JMeter measures the time it took to establish the connection, including SSL handshake. Note that connect time is not automatically subtracted from latency. In case of connection error, the metric will be equal to the time it took to face the error, for example in case of Timeout, it should be equal to connection timeout.

So overall elapsed time will be `Connect Time + Latency + Time for processing your request on server side`

If you have high Latency and Connect time you can still load test from the UK, however keep in mind that you might need to increase the number of threads (virtual users) in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)(s) to keep your server busy while requests and responses are going back and forth. A good approach would be implementing some form of goal-oriented scenario and focus not on simulating virtual users, but rather reaching desired throughput in terms of requests per second. Check out [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/), given you connect them via [Schedule Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) JMeter will be able to kick off extra threads to reach/maintain the target throughput to compensate high latency.

You can install both test elements using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest question is your user performance.  Is this an international site?  What type of traffic are you expecting in order to verify performance?

The other thing to keep in mind is network performance, if you know that you can always subtract that form you results to get the actual site values vs network